# Output true value for Foreach statement

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am trying to output the value which checks if the condition matches, but instead its returning value whether it is true or not.

```
$result = "VM name"

$name= get-content C:\monitor\Serverlist\Serverlist2.txt
    foreach($nam1 in $name)

    { 
    #Write-output $nam1
    $l=Get-Vm -computername $nam1 |out-string


           foreach ($l2 in $l)
            {
             if ( $l2 = $result ) 
            {
             Write-Output $input "is in" $nam1

             }

             else

             {
           ""
             }
            }
           }
```

but output i am getting is true in all case, where as VM name is present in comp1 only.

```
VM name is in comp1
VM name is in comp2
VM name is in comp3
```

If statement should return condition if it matches? I also tried looping if statement outside 1st foreach loop but that gives me result of last comp "comp3" even the matching result is in comp1.
Any Idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Also, don't use `Out-String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=` sign not for conditional testing, it's for setting the value:

```
        if ( $l2 = $result ) 
        {
         Write-Output $input "is in" $nam1
        }
```

Should be... *(note that I'm using `-eq` to test equality)*

```
        if ( $l2 -eq $result ) 
        {
         Write-Output $input "is in" $nam1
        }
```

But even that wouldn't work.  Your conditional test between a `string` and a `VirtualMachine` object won't work.  Here's what you want...

```
        if ( $l2.Name -eq $result ) 
        {
         Write-Output $input "is in" $nam1
        }
```

In the above snippet, I'm doing a conditional test on `VirtualMachine.Name` (type `string`) with your variable.